# Change the character of line and column of RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I need to change the character in `RichTextBox` where I can put a integer in row_textbox and column_textbox then I can change the character in that row and column. Here the sample code:

```
         //declarations
        int row = Int16.Parse(tbox_row.Text);
        int column = Int16.Parse(tbox_column.Text);
        // Get the row
        row = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        int row_rb = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(row);

        // Get the column.
        column = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(row);
        int column_rb = row - column;

        tbox_sample.Text = "line: " + row.ToString() + ", column: " + column.ToString();
```

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh i have a textbox of row and column then in that row and column of richtextbox i will change the value of the string

Comment: You select it and then change the selected text, as always..